# GetManifestStream in silverlight to load xml file

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application in which I am doing the following thing to load a XML file, and further to parse it.

I have set the Build Action to Embedded Resource, Copy to Output Directory.
The code that I am using is:

```
try
            {
                Xmlfile = XDocument.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("file.xml"));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Message that I receive as an exception:
*Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: input*

**EDIT**

I tried the following which works (in WPF), but gives problem in Silverlight:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".file.xml")
```

**Error:**

```
'System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Comment: Your question title and tags mention Silverlight, but your question body talks about a WPF app. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to prepend the name of your assembly and its subfolders, like this:

```
string assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
XDocument.Load(assemblyName + ".subfolder.file.xml");
```

Sometimes it's not clear exactly what the subfolder(s) should be.  If that's the case, just inspect the names directly using this:

```
string[] names = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Comment: `string[] names = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();` is showing the file `Wpfapplication12.file.xml`. But on trying to get the file using the above code in your answer, I still get the 'File not found error: ..//bin/Debug/WpfApplication12.file.xml not found'

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer yet, but the prepend "solution" does not work for Silverlight 5 apps.

If you complie the proffered code withing a Silverlight 5.0 project you will get
  'System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName()' is inaccessible due to its protection level at compile time.

For the record I get similar errors for:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName();
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
<someAssembly>.GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

For the other GetName() overload you get the same protection error.

```
<someAssembly>.GetType(fullyQualifiedTypeName, false, true);
```

'System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(string, bool, bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I suspect the protection level error stems from the fact that Silverlight apps are only partially trusted code and Reflection by its nature is requires high trust. But, in the end I merely speculating about what is behind the Microsoft code wall.

Is there an article on MSDN or somewhere that describes which portions of C# reflection vis a vis Assemblies that is disabled/protect when incorporated into a Silverlight 5 web app?